# Google maps marker in one country

Tags: javascript, google-maps, delimiter

Does anyone know how to just enable markers for a specific country in google maps, using the javascript api.

this is my code with the options for initialize the map: (in other method I show it, it's working):

```
latitud = "-33.400491820565236";
    longitud = "-70.68363189697266";

    //Se crea un objeto MapOptions con los valores de la lat y long para centrarlas
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitud, longitud),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    //Se crea un objeto de tipo Map para que el mapa se muestre en el div especificado
    mapPunto2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(idDivMapa), mapOptions);
```

I want to enable markers just for Chile. Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't see any markers in the posted code? What do you mean by "I want to enable markers just for Chile"?

Comment: You need to create your own markers to "enable" them, so only create markers that have co-ordinates in Chile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking out the GeoCoder functionality? 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Just by knowing a countries name, you can return the LAT and LONG and add marker/markers

**Example:**

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function setCountryToSelect(countryToSelect) {
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': countryToSelect}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: map,
           position: results[0].geometry.location
       });
    } else {
      alert("Error: " + status);
    }
});
}

setCountryToSelect('USA');
setCountryToSelect('England');
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late answer... why i did, finally, was, using The Google Maps Geocoding API, ask for Country_ID, then, this way, i can filter by country_id when a marker is being adding to map. I will try your code, i think it's more simple that mine.. thank you!